# Demonstration of Scale Balancing

Tags: c++, algorithm, programming-challenge

> Have the function ScaleBalancing(int vector, int vector) read vectors
>   which will contain two elements, the first being the two positive
>   integer weights on a balance scale (left and right sides) and the
>   second element being a list of available weights as positive integers.
>   Your goal is to determine if you can balance the scale by using the
>   least amount of weights from the list, but using at most only 2
>   weights.
>
> For example: if vector is ["[5, 9]", "[1, 2, 6, 7]"] then this means
>   there is a balance scale with a weight of 5 on the left side and 9 on
>   the right side. It is in fact possible to balance this scale by adding
>   a 6 to the left side from the list of weights and adding a 2 to the
>   right side. Both scales will now equal 11 and they are perfectly
>   balanced. Your program should return a comma separated string of the
>   weights that were used from the list in ascending order, so for this
>   example your program should return the string 2,6
>
> There will only ever be one unique solution and the list of available
>   weights will not be empty. It is also possible to add two weights to
>   only one side of the scale to balance it. If it is not possible to
>   balance the scale then your program should return the string not
>   possible.

How can I make improvements to my code? I also want to know if my approach was a good way to solve this problem.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
bool all_Positive(const T start, const T end) {
    T it;
    for (it = start; it != end; it++) {
        if (*it < 0) return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool every_Num_Positive(std::vector<int> &integerWeights, std::vector<int> &availableWeights)
{
    if (all_Positive(integerWeights.begin(),integerWeights.end()) && all_Positive(availableWeights.begin(), availableWeights.end()))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

bool check_Length(std::vector<int> &integerWeights, std::vector<int> &availableWeights)
{
    if (integerWeights.size() == 2 && !availableWeights.empty())
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

std::vector<int> find_2_Nums_That_Add_To_Difference(std::vector<int> &availableWeights, int difference)
{
    std::vector<int> result;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < availableWeights.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (std::size_t j = i + 1; j < availableWeights.size(); ++j)
        {
            if (availableWeights.at(i) + availableWeights.at(j) == difference)
            {
                result.push_back(availableWeights.at(i));
                result.push_back(availableWeights.at(j));
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

std::string find_2_Nums_That_Minus_To_Difference(std::vector<int> availableWeights, int difference)
{
    std::vector<int> possible;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < availableWeights.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (std::size_t j = i + 1; j < availableWeights.size(); ++j)
        {
            if (abs(availableWeights.at(i) - availableWeights.at(j)) == difference)
            {
                return std::to_string(availableWeights.at(i)) + "," + std::to_string(availableWeights.at(j));
            }
        }
    }
    return "NOT POSSIBLE";
}

std::string scale_Balancing(std::vector<int> integerWeights, std::vector<int> availableWeights)
{
    if (check_Length(integerWeights, availableWeights) && every_Num_Positive(integerWeights,availableWeights))
    {
        int difference = std::abs(integerWeights.at(1) - integerWeights.at(0));

        std::vector<int> possibleResults = find_2_Nums_That_Add_To_Difference(availableWeights, difference);

        if (std::find(availableWeights.begin(),availableWeights.end(),difference) != availableWeights.end())
        {
            return std::to_string(difference);
        }
        else if (!possibleResults.empty())
        {
            return std::to_string(possibleResults.at(0)) + "," + std::to_string(possibleResults.at(1));
        }
        else
        {
            return find_2_Nums_That_Minus_To_Difference(availableWeights, difference);
        }
    }

    return "NOT POSSIBLE";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unnecessary includes: These

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <numeric>
```

are apparently not needed.

In your function

```
template <typename T>
bool all_Positive(const T start, const T end) {
    T it;
    for (it = start; it != end; it++) {
        if (*it < 0) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

the test should be

```
        if (*it <= 0) return false;
```

otherwise zero would qualify as positive number. As @tinstaafl
already said, verifying the input is usually not necessary for
programming challenges.

The functions

```
std::string find_2_Nums_That_Minus_To_Difference(std::vector<int> availableWeights, int difference)
std::string scale_Balancing(std::vector<int> integerWeights, std::vector<int> availableWeights)
```

take the vectors as values, you probably want to pass them by
reference to avoid making copies.

In `scale_Balancing()` a possible pair of weights adding to the difference is
 determined (and possibly discarded) *before* searching for a single weight.

It is also confusing that

```
std::vector<int> find_2_Nums_That_Add_To_Difference(...)
```

returns a vector, but

```
std::string find_2_Nums_That_Minus_To_Difference(...)
```

returns a string.

Both functions actually return a pair of integers or “nothing.”
In C++17 you can use a

```
std::optional<std::pair<int, int>>
```

for that purpose. If C++17 is not available then returning a `std::pair<int, int>`
(with `{ -1, -1 }` indicating “not found”) would be an alternative to
returning a vector.

Better (and slightly shorter) function names would be

```
find_pair_with_sum(std::vector<int>&nums, int sum)
find_pair_with_difference(std::vector<int>&nums, int difference)
```

Note that both functions can be implemented with \$ O(n) \$
complexity if the array is sorted, see for example

- [Find a pair with the given difference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-pair-with-the-given-difference/)
- [Given an array A[] and a number x, check for pair in A[] with sum as x](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-that-given-a-set-a-of-n-numbers-and-another-number-x-determines-whether-or-not-there-exist-two-elements-in-s-whose-sum-is-exactly-x/)

With those changes, the main function simplifies to

```
std::string scale_Balancing(std::vector<int>& integerWeights, std::vector<int>& availableWeights)
{
    int difference = std::abs(integerWeights[1] - integerWeights[0]);
    sort(availableWeights.begin(), availableWeights.end());

    if (std::binary_search(availableWeights.begin(), availableWeights.end(), difference)) {
        return std::to_string(difference);
    }

    auto sum_pair = find_pair_with_sum(availableWeights, difference);
    if (sum_pair) {
        return std::to_string(sum_pair->first) + "," + std::to_string(sum_pair->second);
    }

    auto diff_pair = find_pair_with_difference(availableWeights, difference);
    if (diff_pair) {
        return std::to_string(sum_pair->first) + "," + std::to_string(sum_pair->second);
    }

    return "NOT POSSIBLE";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin R. By the way, "if (sum_pair)" does not work, I fixed this problem by "if (sum_pair.first && sum_pair.second)"

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me that you're over thinking this a bit.

The problem statement says that each vector will have positive integers.  It is very superfluous to check for that.

Always try to avoid using the concatenation operator(`+`) for joining strings, the `stringstream` is much better for that.

You run 2 nested loops twice once to check for  numbers that add to difference and those that subtract to difference.  My thought is use one loop and use the `std::binary_search` function in the `algorithm` header.  When each weight is subtracted from the difference all you need is the absolute value of the result and check if that weight exists.

Something like this:

```
const string DEFAULT_MESSAGE = "NOT POSSIBLE";
typedef vector<int>::iterator iter;
string ScaleBalancing(vector<int>& scale, vector<int>& weights)
{
    stringstream ss;
    sort(scale.begin(), scale.end());
    sort(weights.begin(), weights.end());
    int difference = scale[1] - scale[0];
    iter begin = weights.begin();
    iter end = weights.end();
    if (binary_search(begin, end, difference))
    {
        return to_string(difference);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < weights.size(); ++i)
    {
        bool isNeg = false;
        int tempDifference = difference - weights[i];
        if (tempDifference < 0)
        {
            tempDifference *= -1;
            isNeg = true;
        }
        if (tempDifference > weights.back())
        {
            return DEFAULT_MESSAGE;
        }
        if (binary_search(begin,end,tempDifference) && tempDifference!= weights[i])
        {
            if (isNeg)
            {
                ss << tempDifference << ',' << weights[i];
            }
            else
            {
                ss << weights[i] << ',' << tempDifference;
            }
            return ss.str();
        }
    }
    return DEFAULT_MESSAGE;
}
```

Comment: Even though the problem statement did say that, I just wanted to add it as a challenge. Do you usually capitalize your const and constexpr variables?

Comment: @austingae - The concept of capitalizing constants  is fairly standard in c++.